# Angular Material - Override the overlay css at the component level

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I am trying to override some `cdk-overlay` css at the Angular component level, but it doesn't work - even if I use `:host ::ng-deep`

The material `select` dropdown here (`mat-select-content`) is a child of `cdk-overlay-pane`:

```html
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="...">
<div class="ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanel ng-tns-c19-5 mat-select-panel ng-star-inserted mat-select-panel-done-animating" ng-reflect-klass="mat-select-panel " style="transform-origin: 50% 6.66667px 0px; font-size: 12px; opacity: 1; min-width: calc(100% + 32px); transform: scaleY(1);">
<div class="mat-select-content ng-trigger ng-trigger-fadeInContent" style="opacity: 1;">
 <mat-option _ngcontent-c15="" class="mat-option mat-selected mat-active" role="option" value="Basic" ng-reflect-value="Basic" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-0">
  <span class="mat-option-text">Basic</span>
   <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple"></div>
 </mat-option>
 <mat-option _ngcontent-c15="" class="mat-option" role="option" value="Advanced" ng-reflect-value="Advanced" id="mat-option-1">
  <span class="mat-option-text">Advanced</span><div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple"></div>
 </mat-option>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to move this css from my `main.scss` file into the component level, so it doesn't affect any other pages:

```css
.cdk-overlay-container.dark-theme{

    .cdk-overlay-pane, .mat-select-content {    //  search panel
        background: black;
        border: .5px solid #323030;        
    } 
}
```

But when I move it into my.component.scss, IT DOESN'T WORK:

```css
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane, .mat-select-content {    // search panel
        background: black;
        border: .5px solid #323030;        
    }
```

I also need to add this style to class `cdk-overlay-pane` in my component scss:

```css
element.style {
    min-width: 222.333px;
    pointer-events: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 115px;
    left: 313px;
    transform: translateX(-16px);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add a comma, otherwise it treats it as a new CSS selector

Comment: sorry, a comma on which selector ?

Comment: Sorry, I've just looked closer, and realised that was intentional. You can try `::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane, ::ng-deep .mat-select-content ` though and see if that helps

Comment: Almost. I'm trying to isolate the style to class name `.search-dropdown`. So your suggestion worked here - `::ng-deep .search-dropdown .cdk-overlay-pane, ::ng-deep  .mat-select-content`, but this doesn't `::ng-deep .search-dropdown .cdk-overlay-pane, ::ng-deep  .search-dropdown  .mat-select-content` . So strange.

Comment: Problem is that I can easily affect other pages within other overlays if I don't use the proper class hierarchy...

Comment: Add `:host` before `::ng-deep`. If it does not work, maybe create an example on stackblitz.com

Comment: Please add an example on StackBlitz to dive into your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Content within the overlay container cannot be styled from within a component because the overlay content is not a child of the component. The overlay container is a child of the page's `body` element, so style for its content needs to reside in your global style. However, you can selectively apply style to a specific select panel inside the overlay container using the `panelClass` property of `MatSelect`:

```
<mat-select panelClass="my-panel-class">...

.my-panel-class .mat-select-content {
    background: black;
    border: .5px solid #323030;        
}
```

Comment: I will give that a try.

Comment: This is also the correct answer because restyling shared classes such as `cdk-overlay-pane` can cause [unintended consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763313/mattooltip-wont-be-aligned-to-its-object-button-in-the-whole-project-how-do-i).