# MatTooltip won't be aligned to its object/button in the whole project, how do I align it?

Tags: angular-material, tooltip

I'm building a project with Metronic (downloaded from themeforest). I'm using the angular version of it and I have this style problem where the tooltips have an offset to the left.

Tried to reinstall angular, tooltip, hammerjs, but nothing changed

In pages.module.ts:

```
import { MatTooltipModule, MatInputModule, ... } from "@angular/material";
@NgModule({
declarations: [ ... ],
imports: [
    ...
    MatTooltipModule,

],
providers:[],
entryComponents:[
    // multiple components for my custom dialogs
]
});
```

When I actually use it:

```
<button matTooltip="tooltip"><mat-icon>new</mat-icon></button>
```

I also tried using the `matTooltipPosition` with all the possible values, but nothing changed.

[Link to image](http://examcopy.altervista.org/screenshot.png)

As you can see in the image, when I hover the button the actual tooltip is shown way to the left of it, not aligned to the button.*

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that I set

```
.cdk-overlay-pane{
    min-width:40vw;
}
```

in my `styles.scss` to make every dialog box big enough, but the same class was used by the tooltips as well, so making that CSS directive more specific or just deleting it solves the problem.

Comment: this was exactly my issue

Comment: Also my issue, this must have been a bugger to track down.  [Quite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56197245/2738164) a [few people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453331/angular-material-override-the-overlay-css-at-the-component-level) on SO appear to try styling `.cdk-overlay-pane` (for example to resize modals), but that now appears to be bad advice given its broad usage and subtle side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try set position of `matTooltip` with `matTooltipPosition="below"`

```
<button matTooltip="tooltip" matTooltipPosition="below"><mat-icon>new</mat-icon></button>
```

official documentation for all positions:
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#positioning

Comment: Yeah, I did try that with all the possible positions, but it is still stuck there, far away from the button

Comment: This will not change much. "below" is the default behaviour for MatTooltipPosition