# how can i apply custom class next to cdk-overlay-pane for material menu in angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular7

i have requirement where i want to create mega menu using angular material menu. now i want apply some style to cdk-overlay-pane using own custom class
for that i used class and panelClass attribute but doesn't work for me.

i tried to apply custom class on  using class and panelClass attribute. please check below code

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" panelClass='CustomClass'>
```

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class='CustomClass'>
```

none of above code is working for me.

it should be apply custom class next to cdk panel class when angular material open menu cdk overlay

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" panelClass='CustomClass'>

Comment: <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class='CustomClass'>

Comment: update the answer to change styling based on your own custom class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your **css**... the hierarchy is quite unique and complex when you open up the inspect element:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-menu-panel .mat-menu-content { background: lightblue }
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-menu-panel .mat-menu-content .mat-menu-item {color: blue;}
```

**Update**:

if you'd like to use your own class, then refer to the correct panel using your class
relevant **css**:

```
::ng-deep .customClass .mat-menu-content {border:1px solid red; background:lightblue}
::ng-deep .customClass .mat-menu-content .mat-menu-item {color:blue;}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class='customClass' >
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

you can see a [working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvthj1?file=app%2Fmenu-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thanks it's work for my but what if i want apply custom class for cdk overlay how can i do that any idea??

Comment: You can put your class, but then traverse via CSS down to pane > panel > content to style the pane / panel / buttons

Comment: Awesome. I tried many ways to display angular material date picker over bootstrap modal. Searched a lot in the internet but there is no proper solution. You made my day. The following lines have worked for me    ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container  {
    z-index: 1200 !important;
  }

Comment: Be very careful about styling these components so broadly - they can have unintended consequences, often in modules you wouldn't anticipate would be affected (e.g., [tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763313/mattooltip-wont-be-aligned-to-its-object-button-in-the-whole-project-how-do-i)).